# Turn array into objects, and add key values from another object

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of the same length:

A simple array

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
```

And another array of objects

```
arr2 = [
  {cat: "a", other: 0},
  {cat: "b". other: 0},
  {cat: "c", other: 0}
]
```

I want to combine the two arrays into a new array, taking the values from the first array and giving them the key `node`, and combining all the `cat`s as below:

```
end = [
 {node: 1, cat: "a"},
 {node: 2, cat: "a"},
 {node: 3, cat: "a"},
]
```

Comment: I did not downvoted this post. BUT you have not us your `attempt` to achieve the desired results. Ideally you need to use your `code` with issue you are having so that a proper solution can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr2 = [
  {cat: "a", other: 0},
  {cat: "b", other: 0},
  {cat: "c", other: 0}
];
arr1 = [1,2,3];

let res = [];
for (let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    res.push({node: arr1[i], cat: arr2[i].cat});
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just map through it and build the array and create the new objects at the same time

This one merged all objects together

```
    arr1.map((value, idx) => ({ ...arr2[idx], node: value }))
```

If you want to just get the cat of arr2 then do this

```
    arr1.map((value, idx) => ({ cat: arr2[idx].cat, node: value }))
```

```js
arr1 = [1,2,3];

arr2 = [
  {cat: "a", other: 0},
  {cat: "b", other: 0},
  {cat: "c", other: 0}
];

end = arr1.map((value, idx) => ({ cat: arr2[idx].cat, node: value }));

console.log(end)
```